# How to activate specific excel window and specific excel sheet using com objects autohotkey?

Tags: microsoft-excel, autohotkey

I am using following script to activate specific excel window-

```
f5::
WinWait, Microsoft Excel - B  [Compatibility Mode], 
IfWinNotActive, Microsoft Excel - B  [Compatibility Mode], , WinActivate, Microsoft Excel - B  [Compatibility Mode], 
WinWaitActive, Microsoft Excel - B  [Compatibility Mode],  
return
```

but `winwait` command or `ifwinnotactive` command is not working properly if there are 3-4 excel windows are minimized.
For example there are 3 excel windows are minimized say they are A, B and C and I want to activate only B window and also its sheet3 then what command should I use?
Is it possible via com objects to activate specific excel window and specific sheet?

As following com object codes only activates only one existing excel file. like-

```
f6::
Xl := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
Xl.Visible := True
return
```

How can I add specific excel file name (which is minimized) and sheet name in com object coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Active Window Info" spy program from AHK. It's called AU3_Spy.exe and it's in the AHK installation folder. Run the spy window, click on the open excel sheet and it will give you the exact class name for that file (under "Window Title & Class) which you should use in your script.

Example:
IfWinActive, ahk_class XLMAIN

[image]